# Shell Script for Yesterday's Date

Tags: terminal, command-line

I'm trying to execute the following shellscript with hazel app on any file in the folder.  It works, but the only thing thats causing a problem is the date for yesterday.

```
#! /bin/bash

saveDir="TJ"
dd=$(date --date='yesterday' +'%m-%d-%Y')
for file in *.csv ; do
    saveName="${saveDir}/TJ ${dd}.csv"
    cut -d',' -f2,14 "$file" > "$saveName"
done
```

Any ideas why it isn't working?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Try using date like this:

```
dd=$(date -v -1d '+%m-%d-%y')
```

as mentioned `yesterday` is part of GNU Date, but using an offset of -1d should be equivalent for OS X use.

Answer (score 3):

The date utility bundled with OS X is not GNU date (which accepts the `--date` option).

You can use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install it.

You can probably use Perl to get what you want:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -le 'print strftime("%d-%m-%Y",localtime(time()-86400))'
# or
perl -MTime::Piece -MTime::Seconds -le 'print((Time::Piece->new - ONE_DAY)->dmy)'
```